# What is the difference between an Ordered Set and a Completely Ordered Set?

Tags: definition, order-theory

When is a set called an Ordered Set and when is it called a Completely Ordered Set?

Comment: Could that be a translation mishap for *totally ordered* or should it maybe be a *(Dedekind) complete order*?

Comment: An ordered set is called completely ordered if every non-empty subset contains a smallest element. E.g. $(0,1)$ is not completely ordered under the usual order on real numbers.

Comment: @Improve, Is $[0,1]$ a completely ordered set?

Comment: @Improve: You're mistaken. What you describe is  a *well-ordered* set.

Comment: @Bernard Mícheál O'Searcoid in Elements of Abstract Analysis defines a set S to be completely ordered to mean that a set S is totally ordered and that every non-empty subset which has an upper bound also has a supremum in S. I am also quite sure I have seen the definition I posted above. I think the conclusion is that not everyone agrees on what a completely ordered set should mean. I am in no position to claim what is the most common usage.

Comment: @Improve that definition involves a totally ordered set that has the so-called *least upper bound property*. That definitely is weaker than demanding that every non-empty subset has a smallest element. I am sure that *completely ordered* is not meant to be the same as *well ordered*.

Comment: You're probably right, there's no universal convention. The terminology you mention seems to  abstract the properties of $\mathbf R$, and is not of general use.

Comment: @drhab: I think I've got it: `completely`, in this  context,  refers to the fact that it is a property equivalent to `completeness` (in the topological sense) of $\mathbf R$.

Comment: @drhab Basic Language of Mathematics by Juan Jorge Schäffer and Oxford Users' Guide to Mathematics by Eberhard Zeidler seem to define it in the same spirit as my first comment. These are books that happened to agree with the definition after a google search, and not a carefully selected sample. Other books define it as meaning the same as totally ordered. There is even a notion of pre-complete order. Looking more carefully at OP's question I assume that he means it in the sense of totally ordered.

Comment: @Improve Well, let me restrain myself: I am *almost* sure. I wish there was some general standard in situations like this. However, that is a dream that will never come true, I think.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, I also think you've got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `completely ordered` is another phrasing for a `totally ordered` or `linearly ordered` set, i.e. an ordered set for which any two elements can be compared.

As an example, $\mathbf R$ is a totally ordered set (the order can be defined by the relation $x\le y\iff y-x\ge 0$).

Given  a set $E$, we may consider the set $\mathcal P(E)$ of its subsets, and order it by `inclusion`: we say $X\prec Y$ if every element of $X$ is an element of $Y$, i.e. if $X\subset Y$. It is not a total order if $E$ has at least two elements, since if $a \ne b$, neither $\{a\}$ not $\{b\}$ is contained in the other.

Another example is the set $\mathbf N$ of natural numbers: we say $n\prec p$ if $n$ is a `divisor` of $p$, i.e. if there exists a natural number $p'$ such that $p=np'$. Thus for instance we can't write $ 2\prec 3$ nor $3\prec 2$.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Is there an example of (1) an ordered set and (2) a totally ordered set?

Comment: Please see my updated answer.